# Tabulator - is there a way to print just selected rows

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using the Tabulator javascript table:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/print

Is there a way to just print selected rows:

```
 var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    printAsHtml:true, //enable html table printing
    printVisibleRows:false, // print all rows in the table
});
```

What i am looking for is an option like "printSelectedRows: true) or some sort of work-around i can use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option. One work around I can think of is a filter that results in only the rows you want being visible and not using printVisibleRows:false. Then only those rows would print. This of course depends on the row selection having some common element. For ad-hoc selection work around's I can think of are:
1) Moveable rows:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/move#rows
Move the rows you want to the visible part of the table.

2) Move between tables:
Move rows to another table for printing.
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/move#rows-table

Comment: Is their any way I could get the row data myself, should be pretty simple using rows selected api, then apply that to a template - Tabulator has some sort of print template that handles header footer, rows - What i really need is just that template/css and then i can render my own html and print it. Thoughts?

Comment: I forgot about `printFormatter` here(http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/print). You can also look at (https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/print.js) and (https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/html_table_export.js)

Comment: Is there some way I can get the source HTML for the table print function - or use tabulator to make my own html for print. I need to push the HTML server side so I can render a PDF. Any ideas?